# Ratio of Hypergeometric Functions

Tags: complex-analysis, hypergeometric-function

Show that if $a$ is a negative integer while $b$ and $c$ are not integers, then the ratio $$\dfrac{F(a,b;a+b-c+1;1-z)}{F(a,b;c;z)}$$ is independent of $z$ and find its value.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** From gammatesters answer, we may conclude: $$\dfrac{F\left( a,b;c;z \right)}{F(a,b;a+b-c+1;1-z)} = \frac{\Gamma(c)\Gamma(c-a-b)}{\Gamma(c-a) \Gamma(c-b)} = \dfrac{(c-a)_a}{(c-b)_a},$$ using the definition of the Pochhammer symbol $(a)_n=\dfrac{\Gamma(a+n)}{\Gamma(n)}$.

Comment: Try wiriting the hypergeometric functions in it basic form (ratio of rising factorials) and doing a bit of algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: See Abramowitz and Stegun 15.3.6
$$F\left( a,b;c;z \right) = \frac{\Gamma(c)\Gamma(c-a-b)}{\Gamma(c-a) \Gamma(c-b)} F(a,b;a+b-c+1;1-z)\\
+ (1-z)^{c-a-b}  \frac{\Gamma(c)\Gamma(a+b-c)}{\Gamma(a) \Gamma(b)} F\left(c-a,c-b;c-a-b+1;1-z\right)$$
If $a$ is a negative integer then $\frac{1}{\Gamma(a)}=0\;$ and the second summand vanishes (if there are other assumptions, e.g. $a+b-c\;$ no negative integer etc.)
I guess you can continue from here.

Comment: Cheers, got it!